# Given a table with time periods, query for a list of sum per day

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table that says how many items of something are valid between two dates.
Additionally, there may be multiple such periods.

For example, given a table:

```
itemtype  | count | start       | end
A         | 10    | 2014-01-01  | 2014-01-10
A         | 10    | 2014-01-05  | 2014-01-08
```

This means that there are 10 items of type A valid 2014-01-01 - 2014-01-10 and additionally, there are 10 valid 2014-01-05 - 2014-01-08.
So for example, the sum of valid items at 2014-01-06 are 20. 
How can I query the table to get the sum per day? I would like a result such as

```
2014-01-01  10
2014-01-02  10
2014-01-03  10
2014-01-04  10
2014-01-05  20
2014-01-06  20
2014-01-07  20
2014-01-08  20
2014-01-09  10
2014-01-10  10
```

Can this be done with SQL? Either Oracle or MySQL would be fine

Comment: How are you wanting to define the `start` and `end` dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax you are looking for is as follows:

For my example below I've defined a new table called `DateTimePeriods` which has a column for `StartDate` and `EndDate` both of which are `DATE` columns.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(NumericColumnName)
    , DateTimePeriods.StartDate
    , DateTimePeriods.EndDate
FROM 
    TableName
    INNER JOIN DateTimePeriods ON TableName.dateColumnName BETWEEN DateTimePeriods.StartDate and DateTimePeriods.EndDate
GROUP BY 
    DateTimePeriods.StartDate
    , DateTimePeriods.EndDate
```

Obviously the above code won't work on your database but should give you a reasonable place to start. You should look into [`GROUP BY`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) and [`Aggregate Functions`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx). I'm also not certain of how universal `BETWEEN` is for each database type, but you could do it using other comparisons such as `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: +1 : This approach is commonly fulfilled using a `calendar` table.  That is a table that contains each date *(say from 1st Jan 2000 to 31st Dec 2069)* along with useful meta-data such as `is_bankholiday`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. First, you need a list of dense dates to query. Using a row generator statement can provide that:

```
select date '2014-01-01' + level -1 d 
from dual 
connect by level <= 15;
```

Then for each date, select the sum of inventory:

```
with 
  sample_data as
    (select 'A' itemtype, 10 item_count, date '2014-01-01' start_date, date '2014-01-10' end_date from dual union all
     select 'A', 10, date '2014-01-05', date '2014-01-08' from dual),
  periods as (select date '2014-01-01' + level -1 d from dual connect by level <= 15)
select 
  periods.d,
  (select sum(item_count) from sample_data where periods.d between start_date and end_date) available
from periods
where periods.d = date '2014-01-06';
```

You would need to dynamically set the number of date rows to generate.

If you only needed a single row, then a query like this would work:

```
with 
  sample_data as
    (select 'A' itemtype, 10 item_count, date '2014-01-01' start_date, date '2014-01-10' end_date from dual union all
     select 'A', 10, date '2014-01-05', date '2014-01-08' from dual)
select sum(item_count)
from sample_data
where date '2014-01-06' between start_date and end_date;
```

Comment: The second statement solved the question exactly like stated (when I dropped the final where clause). Thanks!

Comment: @Claes I'm glad I could help. You are welcome to vote up my answer and/or market it as correct if you feel that is warranted.